# Debugging Oracle Error That Only Occurs With PHP/OCI

Tags: php, sql, oracle, oracle-call-interface

I have a query that is designed to total hours and assign a value depending on the make up of those hours written for an Oracle database.

The query runs fine in Navicat and Toad, and yet I get the following error when running the query using OCI/PHP:

> ORA-00972: identifier is too long

I understand what the message means, but none of the identifiers I have are greater than 30 characters. In case, I aliased the table names and this makes no difference.

My code is as follows:

```
$query ="SELECT
   SUM( ROUND((A.SCHED_DATE_TO - A.SCHED_DATE_FROM)* 24, 1 )),
   SUM( CASE WHEN A.ACTION_TYPE_CODE = 'INSV' THEN ROUND((A.SCHED_DATE_TO-A.SCHED_DATE_FROM)* 24, 1)*30 ELSE 42.50 END)
FROM
   WAREHOUSE.DM_DIM_ACTION \"A\",
   WAREHOUSE.DM_FCT_ACTION \"C\", 
   WAREHOUSE.DM_DIM_TECHNICIAN \"B\"
WHERE
   A.SHUB_ID = C.SHUB_ID
   AND C.FK_TECHNICIAN_WID = B.ROW_WID
   AND A.SITE_VISIT_YN = 'Y'
   AND A.ACTION_TYPE_CODE IN('INSV', 'SURV')
   AND A.STATUS_CODE IN('FDSP', 'DISP', 'ASSN')
   AND A.ASSIGNED_CONTRACTOR_CODE = 'NOCO'
   AND TRUNC( A.SCHED_DATE_FROM )= '20-Sep-11'
   AND B.CELL = 'C04'";

   $stid = oci_parse($conn, $sql); if (!$stid) { echo oci_error($conn); $e = oci_error($conn); print htmlentities($e['message']); }
   $r = oci_execute($stid, OCI_DEFAULT); if (!$r) { $e = oci_error($stid); echo htmlentities($e['message']); }
   $planned = oci_fetch_array($stid, OCI_RETURN_NULLS);
```

What am I doing wrong, and are there any methods/tools that I can use to further diagnose problems like this in future?

**EDIT:**
As per comments, I tried removing the larger fields and simplifying the query to try and narrow down the issue. The following query also provides the same error, with the largest field name being removed.

```
SELECT
   SUM( ROUND((A.SCHED_DATE_TO - A.SCHED_DATE_FROM)* 24, 1 )),
   SUM( CASE WHEN A.ACTION_TYPE_CODE = 'INSV' THEN ROUND((A.SCHED_DATE_TO-A.SCHED_DATE_FROM)* 24, 1)*30 ELSE 42.50 END)
FROM
   WAREHOUSE.DM_DIM_ACTION "A"
WHERE
   AND A.SITE_VISIT_YN = 'Y'
   AND TRUNC( A.SCHED_DATE_FROM )= '20-Sep-11'
```

Comment: `A.ASSIGNED_CONTRACTOR_CODE` is not longer than 30 chars, but `WAREHOUSE.DM_DIM_ACTION.ASSIGNED_CONTRACTOR_CODE` is. Not saying that this is the cause, but that jumped into mind.

Comment: Yes I picked up on that to - unfortunately my knowledge is a bit sketchy and I had assumed that by giving `WAREHOUSE.DM_DIM_ACTION` and alias I could circumvent that.

Why would this query (with or without alias) still work in Toad/Navicat - what do they do differently?

Comment: I can not specifically tell you, because I don't *know*. Maybe the OCI lib in PHP is pre-parsing that? I would just quickly test with a much simpler query if that is actually triggering the limit or not with PHP. Might reveal some error-causing specifics quickly.

Comment: Thanks hakre, sorry I was more pontificating than asking a direct question in regards to other software. Using a smaller query, I assume the issue is with my derived fields.

Comment: I've been an idiot, passing the incorrect `$sql` variable to the parser, not the actual query variable `$query`. :(

Comment: Even if it sounds stupid, please add your solution as an answer below and accept it later. This will help others stumbling over the same error message. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was not the SQL formation, instead I was passing the wrong query string to the `OCI_parse` function.

If the study the code in the question, you'll notice I'm trying to pass `$sql`, not the `$query` variable that I've just defined.

You can never be too careful with multiple queries!